# Magento 1.9 strategery infinite scroll not working

Tags: magento-1.9

Am using `Magento 1.9` theme **coolbaby**. In list page creating a `load more product`, so here am using `strategery infinite scroll` link [enter link description here](https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento-InfiniteScroll)

Am configure every thing in `selector` section
[image]

But i got some error in console, and also products not loaded 
[image]

> **Note: already strategery infinite scroll question asked but am not get result till now.**

Thanks in advance